# Check if user is following user?

Tags: python, django, orm, jinja2

I have a `DetailView` which renders the profile page like so:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'oauth/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_profile'
```

The User model contains fields about the user like `id, username, email, password` I also have another model that has a one to many relationship with this User model. It shows who the User is following like so:

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

Inside my template, I have the following logic:

```
<form method="post" action="">
       {% csrf_token %}
        {% if user in user_profile.followers.all %}
              <input type="submit" class="item profile-nav__follow-btn" value="Following">
        {% else %}
              <input type="submit" class="item profile-nav__follow-btn" value="Follow">
        {% endif %}
</form>
```

I'm trying to check if the user is following that specific user. However, even though it should be true, the Follow input button is shown instead. What is wrong with my logic? Why isn't the Following input button being shown instead?

Comment: Try `{% if user in user_profile.followers.all %}`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Sorry, I edited that before submitting the question. That is what I had originally but it still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Can you post the view that populates that template? Specifically, what is `user` and what is `user_profile`? I'm wondering if perhaps you have accidentally swapped the target and follower by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `user_profile.followers.all` will return list of `Following` instances, not users. And so `user in user_profile.followers.all` will not work. You can check follower with this query:

```
user_profile.followers.filter(follower=self.request.user).exists()
```

Since you cannot use this query in template you can override `get_context_data` and put result into context:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'oauth/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_profile' 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['is_follower'] =  self.object.followers.filter(follower=self.request.user).exists()
        return context
```

Not in template use variable `is_follower` instead:

```
{% if is_follower %}
```

Comment: Hmm when I do this, the context_object_name doesn't display any information. For example, when I do user_profile.username to display the profile's username, it shows up as blank

Comment: Also, if `user_profile.followers.all` returns a list, shouldn't the if statement still work since we are checking if that user exists in that list?

Comment: @user2896120 sorry, as always I missed `return context`:)

Comment: @user2896120 `user_profile.followers.all` contains list of `Following` model. But user is instance of `User` model so it's not exists in `user_profile.followers.all` list directly.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Let's also say on that profile page there's a list of people the user has followed and has not followed. How do I check for each one if they are followed or not?

Comment: @user2896120 didnt test it but you can try `prefetch_related` with `Prefetch` object to filter `followers` with current user. And check `{& if profile.followers %}` in template. See details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related